# Why is here object in front of a method?

Tags: java, spring, object, methods

I am new to Java. And while learning from a tutorial I found this code and I just can't seem to understand this one.

```
public interface ProductRepository {
   List<Product> getAllProducts();

    Product getProductById(String productID);
}
```

Why is **Product** which is **domain** in front of a method here?

Comment: `Product` is the method return type.  You need to study and understand basic Java syntax.

Comment: If I'm not very much mistaken that's the return type

Comment: it's not "in front of" the method, it is part of the method signature. It's the returntype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interface is a group of related methods with empty bodies. Your `getProductById` method returns a `Product` object.

For more information, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

You could implement your interface as such:

```
public class CustomProductRepository implements ProductRepository {

    @Override
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        return new ArrayList<Product>();
    }

    @Override
    public Product getProductById(String productId) {
        for (Product p : getAllProducts()) {
            if (p.getProductId().equals(productId)) {
                return p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `getProductById()` method returing `Product` type object. You need to learn about how to define a method in `Java`. From `Java` [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

More generally, method declarations have six components, in order:

1. Modifiers—such as public, private, and others.
2. The return type—the data type of the value returned by the method, or void if the method does not return a value.
3. The method name—the rules for field names apply to method names as well, but the convention is a little different.
4. The parameter list in parenthesis—a comma-delimited list of input parameters, preceded by their data types, enclosed by parentheses, (). If there are no parameters, you must use empty parentheses.
5. An exception list.
6. The method body, enclosed between braces—the method's code, including the declaration of local variables, goes here.